# Sales Last year without time intellenge functions power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I wanna calculate the sales for last year week without time intellegence function because its not the same week as calendar one.

I calculate current year sales and its working but im having trouble calculating last year sales.

```
sales_weekly=
CALCULATE(SUM(table[Sales]);
FILTER(table;table[Currentweek] <=MAX (table[WeekLY])
```

My data looks like this

[image: Sample of my data]))

Comment: What's the reason for not using time intelligence?

Comment: Because there is no calendar table its not calendar date. its customized

Comment: I highly recommend creating a calendar table, In which, you can create an additional column for the date in your format (CurrentWeek) and set the relationship of calendar table and your fact tables.

Comment: I assume you are using calculated columns? The problem with those in this case is that they are evaluated on a row context level, in other words, it uses only data from that row. When using a value in such a calculation that has to be evaluated over your entire dataset, we need to specificly tell Power BI to use all the data using the ALL() function. Try ```FILTER ( ALL ( table ) ; table[Currentweek] <= MAX ( table[WeekLY] ) )``` I totally agree with @pratik Bhavsar this is not the most elegant solution, I'd have a look in creating a calendar table, also consider using a measure instead

Comment: Also change ```<=``` to ```=``` in this case

Answer (score 0):

I have lookup function to achieve the desired resuts

```
Sales_Weekly = LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Sales],'Table'[Currentweek],'Table'[Weekly])
```

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have a standard calendar, your date dimension becomes even more important.

You'll need 'DimDate'[Year] and 'DimDate'[WeekOfYear]. 'DimDate'[Year] is your fiscal year and 'DimDate'[WeekOfYear] is the integer representing which week of the year it is (your fiscal weeks).

```
Sales Amount = SUM ( 'table'[Sales] )
```

```
Sales PY =
VAR CurrentYear = MAX ( 'DimDate'[Year] )
VAR CurrentWeek = MAX ( 'DimDate'[WeekOfYear] )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    [Sales Amount],
    ALL ( 'DimDate' ),
    'DimDate'[Year] = CurrentYear - 1,
    'DimDate'[WeekOfYear] <= CurrentWeek
  )
```

You'll want to only interact with 'DimDate', never with the date fields in your fact table.